# If the modern understanding of the categorical/hypothetical distinction is better than Kant's, does this undermine the categorical imperative?

Tags: propositional-logic, categorical-imperative, frege, facts

In first-order logic (FOL), we have dedicated connectives for conditionals and disjunctions. Again in FOL, we can turn a conditional into a disjunction, though. [Frege's logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege-logic/#JudgStro) has a judgment stroke, or assertion operator, which works like:

1. (Indicated) The *X* is *A*.
2. (Judged) That *X* is *A* is a fact/It is a fact that *X* is *A*.

Or then:

3. (Judged) As a matter of fact, *X* is *A*.
4. (Judged) The fact of the matter is, *X* is *A*.

So is it enough to say:

5. The fact is, if *X* then *A*.

... in order to convert a hypothetical into a categorical? I ask because, if the categorical/hypothetical distinction is not very robust, and admits of exchanges like between hypotheticals and disjunctions, then I wonder how robust the Kantian distinction between categorical and hypothetical imperatives really is (I presume that he didn't speak of disjunctive imperatives much, if at all, because he at least subconsciously understood that hypotheticals and disjunctions are logically convertible into each other, so anything he might've said against the moral primacy of disjunctions was already said against such primacy for hypotheticals<sup>**E**</sup>).

**Conversion of categoricals into hypotheticals:** and then, however, we should be able to do the other thing, but how?

6. If there are facts at all, then it is a fact that *X* is *A*.
7. If truth be true, then it is true that *X* is *A*.

... and the like? But this makes it seem like the conversion is tantamount to identity conditionals, "If *A*, then *A*," which might seem pointless to arrive at.

---

<sup>**E**</sup>I want to emphasize that qualifier *subconsciously*, because otherwise, Kant's theory of general logic was a perhaps unclear blend of Aristotelian and Stoic considerations. Kant anticipated the FOL use of quantifiers for existence assertions and appreciated that Aristotelian logic is not sufficiently insightful when it comes to conditional/hypothetical judgments. This much foresight is fair to attribute to him, if no more. However, these factoids indicate that Kant's subconscious was at times doing a better job than his overt consciousness, which is not a strange thing to say about him (would it be strange to say it of most any of us?).

Comment: Kant's hypotheticals and disjunctions are not convertible to each other. The hypothetical of two judgments A, B doesn't assert that either A or B is true, but the disjunction of A and B asserts that (exactly) one of the two is true.

Comment: Are you using 'hypothetical' to mean something different from 'conditional'? To convert a conditional into a categorical is simple enough using rules of natural deduction. Both conditionals and categoricals may be either considered or asserted in Frege's terminology.

Comment: Categorical/hypothetical was a distinction in Aristotle's syllogistic - [hypothetical conditionals](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/medieval-syllogism/#Boet) are those that have another conditional in the antecedent. FOL has rich conversion rules that erase such features, so there is no such distinction there. Kant was working from the syllogistic. Frege's indication/judgement distinction is not in FOL either. A statement is asserted just in virtue of stating it, there is no way to "indicate" it without assertion. You can imitate it by downgrading assertion and adding truth meta-predicate.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use modal logic with ◇p for "hypothetically p" or indication, and just p for "categorically p" or assertion. You can even add [actuality operator ○](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/92870/9148) for the latter, although that collapses standard modal logic. It just depends on what you want out of "hypothetical".

Comment: @DavidGudeman Kant says that the third category in every meta-category can be generated from some combination of the first two, and the categories are transposed from forms of judgment, so I would be wary in claiming that he would not take disjunctions to be formulable out of hypotheticals (as well as categoricals).

Comment: @Conifold so would FOL not sustain the categorical/hypothetical distinction as significant enough to mark out a fundamental deontic distinction? I thought it would be harder to make the point in FOL/variants but apparently not... Or can one switch up Kant's wording of his moral theory, to avoid the collapse?

Comment: It seems similar to *a priori* / empirical to me, you have to designate some claims as empirical, and count as *a priori* all and only those derivable without them. Here you designate some as personal ends and count as categorical all and only those derivable without means-end reasoning. Clearly, the natural framework for both is meta-theory and not FOL.

Comment: Can't also points out the important difference that I mentioned: that the hypothetical doesn't assert either of its terms but the disjunctive does assert one of its terms. In any case, the usual truth-functional relationship does not work.

Comment: @DavidGudeman then maybe Kant was "wrong" or "further from truth" or whatever, than modern logic, here, in the sense of having a more deficient theory of the categorical/hypothetical distinction. As an aside, he was epistemologically prosocial enough that, had he lived in the 1900s instead of the 1700s, he would probably have adapted his theory to Fregean logic insofar as he already did adapt his logic to Stoic, not just Aristotelian, considerations. Moreover, he would not, for example, have been an intuitionist or formalist only (in mathematics), but something "weirder."

Comment: @Conifold Would you not consider that marking a proposition as a 'premise' or even an 'assumption' is a way to indicate it without asserting it? Informally, we might say: suppose for the sake of argument... The following proposition is then not asserted. Granted we don't mark it with a symbol as Frege did. The turnstile is different from the assertion marker.

Comment: @Bumble We do that informally, but then we always mix language and meta-language informally, a sign that natural reasoning is not first order. In standard FOL, the only way to 'mark' a premise or assumption is to place them on the left of a conditional, but then they are no longer propositions. In natural deduction systems, they are placed on the left of the turnstile or above the fraction line, but those are meta-symbols. Tarski's T-schema "T(p) iff p" only works if stating a proposition equals asserting it. Withholding judgment is a propositional attitude, so we need modal logic at least.

Comment: @Conifold That seems reasonable, though I would say an assertion is more like a speech act than a modality. Rather than a modal logic, I would rather attempt to represent it using a logic of speech acts. I'm aware of some work that's been done in that area, though not much.

Comment: @Bumble Apparently, that might have been Frege's intention as well. He had "force" as the part of sense that distinguishes indicatives from interrogatives and imperatives, and the assertion mark seems to be of the same nature. Reichenbach later introduced explicit "force indicators" for all of the above, and eventually they were linked to Austin's performatives, see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/speech-acts/#ForIndLogPerLan). "Whether it is worth introducing such force indicators into a logical notation remains an open question" they say.

Comment: Kant wasn't "wrong" or "farther from the truth"; he was doing something different from modern first-order extensional logic.

Comment: @DavidGudeman even if I look at the question in terms of modern logical pluralism, I end up asking: if we no longer credit the categorical/hypothetical/disjunctive distinction with rigidity by default, where does that leave our grounds for accepting the distinction as rigidly important in ethics? Kant did think, incidentally, that his tabulation of categories was an improvement on Aristotle's, by way of the network of base functions in general logic not being so "rhapsodical" (his word) as Aristotle's basis. If he accepted criticism of Aristotle, why would he not accept criticism of himself?

Comment: I would also add that Kant made the categorical/etc. distinction into a factor in his account of the *ens realissimum* re: his talk of "dividing the whole sphere of reality," so I would wonder whether it could indeed be that he was mistaken about the nature of these things by implication (the implication being that his picture of God was logically inadequate, here, for example). Now as far as his ethics go, he also uses phrases like "form of the law" and "ends-in-themselves" but so arguably the importance of that latter phrase would be the most possibly compromised/damaged.

Comment: I didn't mean that Kant shouldn't be criticized; I meant that non-extensional logical operations are not outdated or made irrelevant by modern extensional logic.

Comment: So many ways to say *Yes*. Hypothetically, if we could ask Kant now, do we suppose that his intuition would come up with something earthshaking for us to ponder for 200 more years? I assert it so. The fact of the matter is, I have no background in any of this, having abandoned Philosophy in college when I realized it couldn't tell us the truth in advance. But, on the other hand, "disjunctively", it makes fascinating reading. The Godzilla battle royale